# Different controller based on route :name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

there is a situation where a have multiple controllers like a town_center controller, a  sawmill controller, a quarry controller and so on.

The urls of my application would probably need to be something like /town_center/view or  sawmill/view, quarry/view and the likes.

The problem is how to actually write such routes. For instance, for the town_center controller i have something like :

```
 scope :path => '/town_center', :controller => :town_center do
    get '/view/' => :view, :as => 'town_center'
  end
```

While this works fine, there is a problem. When i actually execute the view action in the town_center controller, there is no simple way to get the id of the building, since it's not present in the url as a params attribute.

One simple idea would be to create a route like :

```
get '/view/:name' => :view, :as => 'view_building'
```

But the problem with that approach is that everything gets redirected to a single controller. So, my question is, how can i make it so that there is an identifier on the url and still redirect to particular controllers ?

Or if you think this is not correct as a general idea, is there a better way to doing that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use RESTful routing, which has become the norm for Rails applications.

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :town_centers
  resources :sawmills
  resources :quarries
end
```

**Edit** Or for singular routes, as suggested in the comments:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resource :town_center
  resource :sawmill
  resource :quarry
end
```

This will automatically give you all of the routes needed for Create, Read, Update, and Destroy your various models.

Running `rake routes` will show you all of the routes that your application makes available.  This will include GET routes of the format `GET /town_centers` and `GET /town_centers/:id`, the latter of which will run a **show** action in your TownCentersController and render your **/views/town_centers/show.html.erb** view template.

If you're new to Rails and have not yet read the **Getting Started** or **Routing** guides, they can be found here:

Getting Started with Rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Rails Routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: yeah, i know of these, but i don't like using resources, i prefer to write my routes manually.  I know that i can just use the :id as part of the url, but i felt it would be redundant since there is just one town_center with a single id. But i guess it's a safe path to walk.

Comment: So you're saying the ID of each entity is static?  If these are hard-coded IDs, then you should be able to pass them as part of the route definition.  For example: `get '/view/' => :view, :as => 'town_center', :id => 14`

Comment: A route resource doesn't have to be plural. You could have resource :town_center. I would not recommend rolling your own routes.

Comment: @Ryan : my only problem with is that the id is based on the database entry. But i would not need to specify the exact id anyway, simply :id is enough.

Comment: @TomLeonard : Why ? I always make my routes manually and never had a problem. I believe it's much better since it does not produce bogus resource entries this way. It's like using scaffolding or not.

Comment: You can disable the routes you don't need using :only or :except qualifiers.  It is not the same thing as using scaffolding.

Comment: @SpyrosP: Sorry. I guess I misunderstood what kind of problem you were having?

Comment: Yes, i thought of using a constraint as well. I mentioned scaffolding because it's also a way of automating things that produces more code than needed most times.

Comment: That's a big difference though.  Scaffolding produces a bunch of code.  Using resources in routing does NOT add code.  The code that handles resources is already in Rails.  It's always in Rails.  As of Rails 3.2, it's highly optimized.  Choosing not to use resources actually makes your routing configuration require more code.